# Boost Beast: how to produce non-chunked response with a custom body when a content length is not readily available?

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-beast

I am trying to implement a custom body type that would hold a parsed JSON tree object. The task seems pretty natural, but I can't find a way to generate non-chunked HTTP messages carrying JSON using Beast. I have a REST client/server implemented by wrapping libmicrohttpd and libcurl, but I would prefer moving to Boost Beast instead.

The problem, as I understand it, is that the body type's `size(value_type const&)` method receives a reference to a body value to be serialized (a JSON tree object in my case), but there is no way to determine the exact length of a stringified JSON without actually stringifying that. However, if I remove the `size()` method, Beast thinks that I am asking for the chunked transfer encoding. Of course, there is nothing wrong with the chunked encoding per se, but for me, it could mean fixing some automation and monitoring scripts, let alone the integration tests.

What I would like to do is to assign a JSON object to the message I am preparing, and then Beast to ask the *writer*, not `body::size()` for the payload size. This seems logical to me, as the actual HTTP message body (serialized JSON) is quite different from a live JSON object in memory, and it is the *body::writer* who produces the body bytes for transferring. Am I wrong?

Anyway, do you think there is a *nice* way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance for your time and effort!

Regards,
Vlad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the kind words, and I'm excited to see the Body customization system getting some attention! Most of what you wrote in the question is correct. If you want Beast to set the Content-Length field when you call `message::prepare_payload` then you have to provide a correct implementation in `Body::size`. The **BodyWriter** is not created until the moment of serialization. The most natural solution to this problem is to avoid providing `Body::size` and let Beast used the chunked Transfer-Encoding when serializing your body type. I should also note that when you serialize the JSON, it is better if you do it a little at a time in the writer instead of converting the entire thing to a string. That is the purpose of having the writer object, to hold intermediate state and allow incremental serialization. Otherwise, you have to allocate memory for the entire serialized representation, which is less efficient.

Update:

`body::size()` and `message::prepare_payload` are not intended to be used the way that you desire. If I am understanding what you want to do, then this function should handle it:

```
/** Prepare a message with a JSON payload.

    This function accepts ownership of a message with a JSON body
    and converts the JSON to string, returning a new message with
    a string body. The Content-Length field is set on the new
    message. All other fields are transferred over unmodified.
*/
template<
    bool isRequest,
    class Allocator>
message<
    isRequest,
    string_body,
    basic_fields<Allocator>>
prepare(
    message<
        isRequest,
        json_body,
        basic_fields<Allocator>>&& m)
{
    message<
        isRequest,
        string_body,
        basic_fields<Allocator>> result{
            std::move(m.base()),
            json_to_string(m.body())};
    result.prepare_payload();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Vinnie! I get it, it is what it is for the moment. But what would you say at such a feature request: give the users yet another point of customisation and allow the writer to calculate the exact content length? This would be very useful for cases like the ones I described. While I generally agree with your argument about piecewise JSON serialization, I still feel that this is more of a workaround than a proper way to go in cases when the said JSON is a hundred chars or less. Thus my proposal to leave it for the users to decide  Thanks again!

Comment: Forgot to mention that I use RapidJSON. It works with whole documents more naturally, so iterative parsing/serialization is basically easier said than done in my case anyway...

Comment: You can implement such a feature yourself by constructing a new message with the serialized version of the JSON just before sending it. I wonder how you are setting the Content-Length. Are you converting the JSON object to a string in the writer? That isn't very efficient. If you have accepted doing the entire conversion at once, then you could just as easily do that conversion outside of the writer in your own function.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include a function which should accomplish what you desire.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and comments! I will continue integrating your library and will post more strange questions if you don't mind 